# I am the owner of a file and I have write access: why can't I save?

Tags: files, osx

I am on OSX 10.9.2

I am locked out of postgres and trying to modify pg_hba.conf to get back in. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919275/can-not-enter-and-change-postgresql-pg-hba-conf-file

I run these commands:

```
$sudo ls -l /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf
-rwx--x--x  1 abramhandler  daemon  4222 Oct  9 20:42 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf
$ whoami
abramhandler
$ sudo subl /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf
```

I make changes and click save and get an error from sublime text 2: Unable to save ~/data/pg_hba.conf

The ls -l command shows that I own the file and have write access. Why can't I save?

Note: I think I am saving to /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf even if I get that error message. Data has a little red circle on it -- which probably indicates a problem.

[image]

Comment: The error from Sublime shows the file at `~/data/pg_hba.conf` while in your terminal it looks like the file is at `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf`.  Are you using `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/` as your home directory?  Or do you have one file open in Sublime Text, when you're looking at a completely different file in the terminal?

Comment: `sudo` changes who you are, though as root you should be able to write to it no matter who owns it.  Also the error indicates it is trying to save it to your home directory instead of /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and  1) tell us what user you are running sublime as 2) what is that user's home directory (`echo ~`)? 3) Have you tried saving to `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf` instead of `~/data/pg_hba.conf`? 4) post the output of `ls -l ~/data/pg_hba.conf`

Comment: he's running Sublime as root, due to the sudo. try changing the owner of the file to root and try again. I think it's denied because root doesn't have access to the file (yes, this is possible - the distinction is that root has the power to _get access_, whereas normal users don't).

Comment: This is probably not an issue, but -- the filesystem is read-write, right?

Comment: What's the red mark for? On /data and /Library?

Comment: Does it work if you try writing to that file from another process, e.g. `echo | sudo tee -a /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf` (don't forget the `-a`!)? Why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: If you need to do an ls to see the file, then you don't have access to the directory to save it. Confirm that subl is really, really running Sublime Text as root (check Activity Monitor or ps).  I suspect it is running it as your user, and the user does not have access to one of the directories in the path.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to chown the containing folder -- not just the file itself. Once I chowned the containing folder I was able to save.

```
$pwd 
Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/
$sudo chown abramhandler data
```

Answer (score 1):

The editor you're using might want to first write out a new file and then rename it to the original name. That way, if something goes wrong in saving the file, the old file is not overwritten before the new one is ready. This minimizes chances for loss of data in case of power interruptions or hardware/filesystem errors, but requires write access to the directory, not just the file itself.

Optionally, the editor might be trying to rename the old file into a backup file (often with a `.bak` or `~` suffix) before writing out the new version of the file. This also requires write permissions to the directory.